# MVC - Dealing with the model and events on the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have what is probably a basic question regarding how to structure an MVC page.

Assume this is my model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   int ProductId
   List<ParameterTable> ParameterTables
   ...
   [other properties]
   ...
}
```

ProductId initially won't have a value, but when its value is selected from a DropDownList it will trigger an event that retrieves the List items associated with that product.

My problem is when I do this AJAX call to get the parameter tables I'm not sure how to handle the response. I've only seen examples where people then manually inserted this data into the page via the jquery. This would mean handling displaying the data in your view (for the first time loading the page) and in the jquery (whenever it changes).

I am wondering if there's a way to somehow pass back a model of sorts that binds my return value of List into my page without needing to specify what to do with each value.

Would I have to have the changing of the ProductId DropDownList trigger an ActionResult that would reload the whole page to do this instead of a JsonResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a partial view with your ajax call.

**Controller action:**

```
public ActionResult Filter(int productId) {
    var product = _repository.Find(productId);
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
         return PartialView("_Product", product);
    }
    else
    {
         return View(product);
    }
}
```